# Toggle button crashes when turned on/off more than once

Tags: java, android, media-player, togglebutton

I can touch the toggle button on (once) and off (once), but if I touch it a third time, it turns on but never plays the music. From there, when I touch it again to turn it off it crashes.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

MediaPlayer mp;
Button startButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.songthing);

    ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton);
    toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                mp.start();
            } else {
                mp.stop();
            }
        }
    });

    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });

}
```

I'm not sure if I should have it within the onCreate method... I've tried to move it but I get very confused with all the brackets and it doesn't work out.

A little more about my code... I'm trying to get the media player to play a song when the toggle button is on and stop it when its off.

EDIT: Logcat says something about `java.lang.IllegalStateException`

XML:

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/ToggleButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textOff="Start"
        android:textOn="Stop" />
```

Comment: Put all trace to here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read a bit about the `MediaPlayer` states [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).
If you call `stop()`, you have to `prepare()` the player again before you can `start()` it.

> Once in the Stopped state, playback cannot be started until prepare() or prepareAsync() are called to set the MediaPlayer object to the Prepared state again.

If preparing the player takes too long, consider using `pause()` followed by `seekTo(0);` as an alternative.